# how are we accessing a class object without referencing it in java?

Tags: java

for example

```
String n;
Scanner Scanner_object= new Scanner(system.in);
n= Scanner_object.next();
```

in this example we have not used the new keyword so how is it assigning the string to the object n .I have tried this code and it is correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
n= Scanner_object.next();
```

`new` is to make new objects. You are not making anything new here, you are just assigning the object that this method call gave you.

Somewhere inside of that method, the string will have been created.

Compare this with your second line, where you are actually creating a "new" instance of Scanner.

Comment: actually i am new to java and from what i have learnt is new keyword is used to allocate memory and assign reference to object but in this example we have not used new to allocate memory and and n does not contain any address so where will be the string scanned by the scanner object be saved. Thanks for answering

Comment: When you declare the variable `n` the memory to store an object in a local variable will be reserved (on the call stack). This memory is of fixed size (usually 64 bits), and used even when set to `null`. When the String is returned from the method, what gets passed around is  a pointer/reference to it. That is what you assign to the variable. No more allocation (that already happened when the String was created inside the method).